# Issue in finding modules to change directory service type of ESXI host to Active Directory using ansible

Tags: vmware, ansible

I am facing issue in finding modules to join ESXI host to Active Directory. I have comes across few modules like win_domain_membership like below. But it is not working out for ESXi host. Please help

```
- win_domain_membership:
      dns_domain_name: ansible.vagrant
      hostname: mydomainclient
      domain_admin_user: testguy@ansible.vagrant
      domain_admin_password: password123!
      domain_ou_path: "OU=Windows,OU=Servers,DC=ansible,DC=vagrant"
      state: domain
    register: domain_state
```

Comment: Any hope on this query :(